# Toggle class that exists on load

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I have HAML markup that looks like this:

```
.image_container{style: 'background-image: url(' + item['image'] + ')'}
      .check
```

I have a CoffeeScript function that adds a class to .image_container on click that looks like this:

```
toggleProduct: (evt) ->
      $(evt.currentTarget).find('.image_container').toggleClass "unselected"
```

I want to add a bit to this function that removes the class .check onclick and adds it back if it's not already there. Initially this sounded like a basic toggle to me but I'm not sure what the solution is because the class already exists in this instance. Is there an easier way to achieve this without making an if/else statement to check if the class is there then either add or remove it? That just seems a bit redundant.

Comment: Do you want to in turns add or remove the class check on each click? You can do `('.image_container').toggleClass 'my-class', my_boolean_value` which will add or remove `my-class` depending on the value of `my_boolean_value`.

Comment: Right. So on load the div with the class of '.check' will be present. I just want to toggle it after it's already there (i.e. when the class '.unselected' is added to '.image_container' the class '.check' will be removed from the child div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly and whenever the class unselected is present, check mustn't and viceversa you could do the following to ensure correlation and avoid having to tackle checking if the class already exists:

```
toggleProduct: (evt) ->
  img = $(evt.currentTarget).find('.image_container')
  img.toggleClass 'unselected'
  $(evt.currentTarget).find('.check_container').toggleClass 'check', not img.hasClass('unselected')
```

Comment: I think your initial explanation is correct, but the class .check should not be added/removed to the div with .image_container, it is its own child div.

Comment: @mtthwbsh I have edited my answer. I assumed that the div to which the class `check` will be added/removed has the class `check_container` to identify him. You should change that selector with one that will find the div in your real scenario.

Comment: The problem is that the class '.check' has a background-image that needs to be there on load, then removed when the class "unselected" is added. So check needs to be there onload, but toggled after that. By changing '.check-container' to '.check' above I can successfully remove the check onclick, but I need to add it back as I toggle '.unselected'. Make sense?

Comment: @mtthwbsh In that case, you should add an extra class like `check_container` (without css styling related) to the div with class `check` to be able to refer to it later when the class `check` has been removed. Using only `check` won't work because once it is removed, you won't be able to refer to the div to add `check` back. Try adding the class `check_container` to your `div.check` and seeing if the code above works.

Comment: Perfect! Much more simple after you explained it, I knew I was on the right track, just needed to execute it. Thanks so much for sticking with me.